How to solve a next.js module not found error
i cloned a next.js repo from github and installed all dependencies but while running the app it runs in a port after there comes some error like module not fuound i dont know why
i reinstlled all the dependencies and changed the version of npm and node but still the same issue.
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\IMGears\PartPricing\partpricing\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib/lib/logger.js'
Require stack:
- D:\IMGears\PartPricing\partpricing\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:15)
    at D:\IMGears\PartPricing\partpricing\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:55:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
    at mod.require (D:\IMGears\PartPricing\partpricing\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:65:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Server.requestListener (D:\IMGears\PartPricing\partpricing\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:135:23)
    at Server.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:1141:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:118:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\IMGears\\PartPricing\\partpricing\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\lib\\start-server.js'
  ]
}

